# Google Sheets, group by unique values in Column A, then show all values in Column B that are in the group

Tags: google-sheets

I have rows of raw data, and I would like the group by column A, and then for each group, list out the values of column B that are in that group. Duplicates in column B (Likes to go to) are fine, and are expected. Example of my dataset:

[image: My dataset example]

And this is the desired output, where each group is displayed horizontally, and under each grouping, a list of that person's places they like to go:

[image: Desired output]

But I have no idea how to do this, and I'm not even sure what it's called. Transposing? Pivot tables? (That can't be right, I'm not aggregating values).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Get unique names with this formula in cell `D1`:

`=transpose(unique(A2:A))`

Then get places for each name with `filter()`:

`=filter($B2:$B, $A2:$A = D1)`